# Estimation of $x$ if $x! = N^{\log N}$

Tags: approximation

If $x! = N^{\log N}\;,$
How can I estimate $x$ in terms of $N$?

Comment: [Stirling's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) might be a good start.

Comment: You can try [Stirling's approximation formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) for $x!$ and take logarithms (which will reduce the right hand side to $(\log N)^2$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we had an approximation for the inverse gamma function $\Gamma^{-1}$, we could apply it to both sides to get $$x \approx \Gamma^{-1} \left( N^{\log{N}} \right)$$

An approximation of $\Gamma^{-1}$ can be found [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/12828/inverse-gamma-function/28977#28977).